# How to add custom images with color to menu items?

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I Have Following Menu Items In My Navigation Drawer

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
```

I have images(.png) of the icons
I tried putting it in the menu item but it comes in grayscale.

How do I put the exact image (with color) as the icon of menu item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom layout to the navigation drawer menu item. Place the image in ImageView of `custom_layout` and check it:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_custom_layout"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="MenuTitle"/>
```

Comment: I have 7 items, it would be so much extra files if i create only and ImageView and TextView for each Item,

Comment: You could have only one custom_layout and can use it in all items.

Comment: How do we access the views of the custom layout? Please help. TIA